# The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]

Tags: eclipse, maven, slf4j

I'm trying to add a spring boot module to an old existing project and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My error is the following :

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jLocationAwareLog.warn(LogAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.callFailedListener(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$failed$7(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:87)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.failed(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
    at fr.edu.paris.muses.MusesPojectionApplication.main(MusesPojectionApplication.java:9)
```

My parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd,http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
  <artifactId>muses</artifactId>

  <version>25.500.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Muses</name>
  <description>Mutualisation du suivi des enseignants stagiaires
    </description>
  <modules>
    <module>muses-service</module>
    <module>muses-client</module>
  </modules>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@gitlabssh.forge.education.gouv.fr:compas/muses.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@gitlabssh.forge.education.gouv.fr:compas/muses.git</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:git:https://gitlab.forge.education.gouv.fr/compas/muses.git</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.7</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>2.10.0</log4j.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.5</joda-time.version>
    <itext.version>2.1.7</itext.version>
    <poi.version>3.6</poi.version>
    <pdfediteur.version>2.0.14</pdfediteur.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <test.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</test.version>
    <slf4jLog4j12.version>1.5.6</slf4jLog4j12.version>
    <apache.commons>3.7</apache.commons>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
         <version>${slf4jLog4j12.version}</version>
         <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>${slf4jLog4j12.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.commons}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfediteur</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfediteur.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${test.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>      
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>      
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
         
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfediteur</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>internal-releases</id>
      <name>Internal releases repository</name>
      <url>https://repository-maven.forge.education.gouv.fr/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>internal-snapshots</id>
      <name>Internal snapshots repository</name>
      <url>https://repository-maven.forge.education.gouv.fr/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
              <version>1.9.4</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

My SpringBoot pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
        <artifactId>muses</artifactId>
        <version>25.500.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
    <version>25.500.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>muses-projection</artifactId>


    <properties>
        <fr.edu.paris.muses-service>${project.version}</fr.edu.paris.muses-service>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <slf4jLog4j12.version>1.5.6</slf4jLog4j12.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
            <artifactId>muses-service</artifactId>
            <version>${fr.edu.paris.muses-service}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>

            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


</project>
```

I've tried almost everything. Adding this code on cocerned dependency

```
         <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
```

I followed this tuto
https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-error-slf4j-the-requested-version-1-7-16-by-your-slf4j-binding-is-not-compatible-with-1-6/

Used the eclipse utility. Which I don't know why adds exclusions on the rest of the project. Which makes it not work anymore since it needs slf4j to work.

[image]

Nothing works

Comment: Your Spring Boot version and dependencies want a newer version of slf4j than you are specifying in your project. You need to migrate your project to the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nitind.

Ok the solution was simple, but I dare to hope that it will not create unexpected bugs.

I modified the version of slf4j but also spring of the parent project

```
(...)
    <spring.version>5.3.13</spring.version>
(...)
    <slf4jLog4j12.version>1.7.16</slf4jLog4j12.version>
(...)
```

I also put the exlude on all dependencies creating duplicates

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
        <artifactId>muses</artifactId>
        <version>25.500.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>fr.edu.paris</groupId>
    <version>25.500.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>muses-projection</artifactId>


    <properties>
        <fr.edu.paris.muses-service>${project.version}</fr.edu.paris.muses-service>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>

            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


</project>
```